# How to get just a list of yum updates

Tags: bash, yum

OK I have always had this problem. I want JUST the available updates listed in a file via bash script from a Linux system (RHEL or Fedora) using yum but I always have to deal with the Header information created which looks like this:

```
    Loaded plugins: XXXX-repo  XXXX-updates
                  : WWWWWW-repo  something-updates  QQQQQ-updates
     Updated packages
     package1.i686         1:234                  RHEL 6.5 updates
     package2.i686         1:234                  RHEL 6.5 updates
     package3.i686         1-234                  RHEL 6.5 updates
     package4.noarch       1.234                  RHEL 6.5 updates
```

All I want is a list of package1,package2, etc. which seems simple enough but it isn't because I can't just grep on "updates" or ":".  Am I looking at this wrongly?  Why would I not want to capture what updates were found in a script?  Should I just update and check what has been updated instead? Thoughts?

PS> I can not use --noplugins option.

EDIT: So far I have come up with this,

```
     sudo yum check-update | grep "\." | awk '(NR >=1) {print $1;}' | grep '^[[:alpha:]]'
```

Basically grab the lines with a period in them, the first line, and make sure it first contains alpha letters.  Perhaps over done but it seems to work.

Comment: are header lines always 3?

Comment: no it can be anything.. hence the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To only print lines following (but not including) "Updated packages"

```
yum check-update | awk 'p; /Updated packages/ {p=1}'
```

Note, on my Fedora system, a blank line separates the "header" from the list of updatable packages, so I would use `awk 'p;/^$/{p=1}'`

Comment: yours was close, I'm not sure who to award here... lol  Thanks.  Basically we can narrow down by lines which are not letters like so:  yum check-update | grep -v plugins | awk '(NR >=1) {print $1;}' | grep '^[[:alpha:]]'

Comment: @MikeQ, awk can pretty much do whatever grep can do, you you can simplify: `yum check-update | awk '!/plugins/ && /^[[:alpha;]]/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 3):

If you pipe the output above into awk using this command:

```
| awk '(NR >=4) {print $1;}'
```

You will get the following output

```
package1.i686
package2.i686
package3.i686
package4.noarch
```

The (NR >=4) tells awk to ignore the first three lines. The {print $1;} tells awk to print the first word of each line.

You can read [here](http://forum.linuxcareer.com/threads/280-SED-how-to-delete-everything-after-a-special-character-on-every-line) for more information on cutting stuff out after certain characters on each line.
You can then use sed if stripping out everything after the . is important

```
| awk '(NR >=4) {print $1;}' | sed s/\.[^\.]*$//
```

Gives the following output

```
package1
package2
package3
package4
```

Then pipe it into another sed command to [replace the linebreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) with a comma.

```
| awk '(NR >=4) {print $1;}' | sed s/\.[^\.]*$// | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
```

Yields the following output

```
package1,package2,package3,package4
```

Comment: This was very close to what I need.  I think we want to do something like this to be more bulletproof:   yum check-update | grep -v plugins | awk '(NR >=1) {print $1;}' | grep '^[[:alpha:]]'

Comment: You don't know for sure if the top header lines are going to be 1, 2 or say even 0 in l length. I want to give part credit, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

### A more flexible solution

The solution below does not assume a specific number of lines in the Header (Ex. in CentOS I got much more header lines).
Nor does it suppose that you are only interested in the repository `updates`.

`yum check-update | awk '/\S+\s+[0-9]\S+\s+\S+/ {print $1 }' > updates`

#### Example

For the following `yum check-update` output

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                    |  31 kB  00:00:00  
 * base: asi-fs-m.net
Excluding mirror: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
Excluding mirror: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
base                                    | 3.6 kB  00:00:00  
cwp                                     | 2.9 kB  00:00:00  
extras                                  | 3.4 kB  00:00:00  
mariadb                                 | 2.9 kB  00:00:00  
remi-safe                               | 3.0 kB  00:00:00  
updates                                 | 3.4 kB  00:00:00  
remi-safe/primary_db                    | 1.4 MB  00:00:00  

openvpn.x86_64          2.4.7-1.el7              epel  
polkit.x86_64           0.112-18.el7_6.1         updates  
pure-ftpd.x86_64        1.0.47-2.el7             epel  
remi-release.noarch     7.6-2.el7.remi           remi-safe
```

You can get

```
openvpn.x86_64
polkit.x86_64
pure-ftpd.x86_64
remi-release.noarch
```

#### Explanation

This solution assumes that the relevant lines have the pattern
`<package name><spaces><version number><spaces><repo name>`

If you want to output a particular repository, then use the pattern
`/\S+\s+[0-9]\S+\s+repo_name/`

#### PS:

If this solution does not work in your system, let me know in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yum check-update | awk '{if($5 ~ /updates/){print $1}}' | tr '\n' ','
```

If the input contains 'updates' on fifth column then print first column and create a csv list.

Comment: This is not an overly secure way to do it.... not bad though, thanks for sharing .. .

Comment: @MikeQ, what do mean by 'overly secure way'? it may not be portable accross distros but it would always work on yours.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this easier:

```
yum check-update -q | awk '{print $1}'
```

Edited.

The explanation of the command:

yum check-update -p - will list the updates in a 3 column list which are package + new version + repository.

awk '{ print $1 }' - will pick up the first column ( package )

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.