# How can I grep a count of available updates from yum check-updates

Tags: bash, grep, yum

I want to check if updates are available, and if so, perform some steps before I install the updates.  I run `yum check-updates` to see a list of updates available for installed packages, but I'd like to `grep` this and get a count that I can use for some logic in a `bash` script.  So ideally, I would like to `grep` that output of `check-updates` and return 0 if there are no updates, or if five updates are available then I would like the `grep` to return 5.

How can I grep this to return the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This combination of awk and grep gives the count of available updates for installed packages:

```
yum check-updates | awk 'p;/^$/{p=1}' | grep -c "\."
```

This was based on the info in [How to get just a list of yum updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698638/how-to-get-just-a-list-of-yum-updates)

Comment: plus one for adding the answer for reference purposes.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. I'm not sure since idk what the output of `yum check-updates` looks like but `awk 'f && /\./{c++} NF{f=1} END{print c+0}'` might be what you want.

Comment: It doesn't work.  Executing check-updates prints messages that include dots like transfer rate, therefore the count of pending packages is not correct.

Answer (score 6):

I like a simpler approach.

"yum -q" reduces the output from yum so it only displays a list of packages.  Combine this with "wc -l" to count the number of lines output.

So to get a count of packages requiring updates I would run

sudo yum -q check-update | wc -l

Comment: I had to filter out empty lines from the yum output. So I ended up doing `sudo yum -q check-update | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l` and that gives me the correct update count.

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of `grep -c`? I've just created some nonsense file, giving following result:

```
Prompt> grep "AA" test.txt
1A01 TCCTTGAAAG
TCAACAAGAA
TCGCAAA
TTTAAAGTCGT
 GGCGGAATCAATAC
GATGGAATATGCGCC
```

If I use `grep -c`, this is the result:

```
Prompt> grep -c "AA" test.txt
6
```

In case this does not answer your question completely, please edit your question and add some more information, just to show what you are looking for.

Also, please be aware that adding  `| wc -l` behind every UNIX command reads the amount of results of that command.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to use the -c option with grep, but I am not sure how to limit the output of check-updates to just the lines that show updates, so right now my count isn't accurate.  I am looking for an answer that deals with the output of the check-updates command, not something generic.

Comment: @Shawn: in that case, please edit your question, show what a regular check-updates output looks like, and what you expect.

Comment: The output varies.  If the output was fixed I would have already written the regular expression, but I am a bash/grep newbie and I don't know all the variations of output that may exist in `check-updates`.  So I don't want to put something specific, and instead, I hope for an answer that accommodates the potential differences.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698638/how-to-get-just-a-list-of-yum-updates) help you?

Comment: Yes, @Thomas, thank you--that gives an answer specific to `yum check-updates` that I was seeking.

Comment: @Shawn Please accept your own answer as correct for future reference.

Comment: I will do so, but StackOverflow says I must wait two more days before I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `-q` for **quiet** is great but you may also want to `grep` **out** any blank lines and also the **trailing** Loaded plugins message.  This works nicely for an accurate count:

```
yum check-update -q|egrep -v "Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager|^$"|wc -l
```